# JavaScript form onchange getting Nan

Tags: javascript, html

I am calling `onchange` event on form but when I checked in console values are coming in `Nan`

HTML

```
<form onchange="calculateHSA(event)">
<div class="col-sm-4">
    <input type="number" name="claim-amnt" id="claim-amnt" required="">
</div>
<div class="col-sm-4">
    <input type="number" name="admin-percent" id="admin-percent" required="">
</div>
<div class="col-sm-4">
    <span class="dataText">Select your province
    </span><br>
    <select name="province" id="province">
        <option value="abc">ABC</option>
    </select>
</div>
</form>
```

JavaScript

```
function calculateHSA(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    const claimAmount = parseInt($(e.target).find('#claim-amnt').val());
    console.log(claimAmount);
    const adminPercent = parseInt($(e.target).find('#admin-percent').val());
    console.log(adminPercent);
    const province = $(e.target).find('#province').val();
    console.log(province);
    displayTaxDetails(claimAmount, adminPercent, province);
}
```

Where I did wrong code?

Comment: Which line shows `NaN`?

Comment: Please provide the code for displayTaxDetails method

Comment: could you console the values found at $(e.target).find('#claim-amnt').val() and $(e.target).find('#admin-percent').val() before the parseInt, to check if it is a valid number ?

Comment: @ThumChoonTat these lines `console.log(claimAmount);` `console.log(adminPercent);` `console.log(province);`

Comment: For starters please use e.currentTarget instead of e.target because e.target can be your text fields but e.currentTarget will always be your form.

Comment: @JordiJordi without parseInt it's showing undefined

Comment: You can get value directly by `$('#claim-amnt').val()`.

Comment: if is undefined, this is the problem, you are parseInt a undefined .. then NAN, check if your input is getting a value. the problem is there, the answer for ur questin is : you are getting NaN because you pass a undefined, not a number to the parseInt, try to solve it and it will work :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please use e.currentTarget instead of e.target because e.target can be your text fields but e.currentTarget will always be your form. This code is working fine.

```
<form onchange="calculateHSA(event)">
<div class="col-sm-4">
    <input type="number" name="claim-amnt" id="claim-amnt" required="">
</div>
<div class="col-sm-4">
    <input type="number" name="admin-percent" id="admin-percent" required="">
</div>
<div class="col-sm-4">
    <span class="dataText">Select your province
    </span><br>
    <select name="province" id="province">
        <option value="abc">ABC</option>
    </select>
</div>
</form>
<script>
    function calculateHSA(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    const claimAmount = parseInt($(e.currentTarget).find('#claim-amnt').val());
    console.log(claimAmount);
    const adminPercent = parseInt($(e.currentTarget).find('#admin-percent').val());
    console.log(adminPercent);
    const province = $(e.currentTarget).find('#province').val();
    console.log(province);
    displayTaxDetails(claimAmount, adminPercent, province);
}
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

There's no need to use `e.target` in your example. You can just access the values from the selectors directly:

```js
function calculateHSA(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  const claimAmount = parseInt($('#claim-amnt').val());
  console.log(claimAmount);
  const adminPercent = parseInt($('#admin-percent').val());
  console.log(adminPercent);
  const province = parseInt($('#province').val());
  console.log(province);
  displayTaxDetails(claimAmount, adminPercent, province);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form onchange="calculateHSA(event)">
  <div class="col-sm-4">
    <input type="number" name="claim-amnt" id="claim-amnt" required="">
  </div>
  <div class="col-sm-4">
    <input type="number" name="admin-percent" id="admin-percent" required="">
  </div>
  <div class="col-sm-4">
    <span class="dataText">Select your province
    </span><br>
    <select name="province" id="province">
      <option value="abc">ABC</option>
    </select>
  </div>
</form>
```

Note that you will get `NaN` in the console for any field that doesn't have a value that can be parsed as an integer. So if you leave the field blank, you're still going to get `NaN` in the console.

Answer (score -1):

You are getting `NaN` because your target element is pointing to the input tag instead of form element

I have made some changes in the function and added new line in the code

```
function calculateHSA(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var form = $(e.target).parent().parent(); // <-- get the form element
    const claimAmount = form.find('#claim-amnt').val();
    console.log(claimAmount);
    const adminPercent = form.find('#admin-percent').val();
    console.log(adminPercent);
    const province = form.find('#province').val();
    console.log(province);
    displayTaxDetails(claimAmount, adminPercent, province);
}
```

have a look at this plunker https://plnkr.co/edit/BQ538zbYBk857zT1wAgT